# Nested patterns: why does the '*' regex operator stop before '+'?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

This is the (simplified) text that I am working on:

```
# header 1
Lorem ipsum

# random header
dolor si

# header 2
amet
```

I would like to catch this snippet A:

```
# header 1
Lorem ipsum

# random header
dolor si
```

If I use regex a: `# header 1(?:[^#]+|(?!# header 2)#)*`, I get snippet A as expected.

But if I use regex b: `# header 1(?:[^#]*|(?!# header 2)#)*`, I only get snippet B:

```
# header 1
Lorem ipsum
```

I would expect to get snippet A in both cases - what's happening in the `*` case that makes the match stop prematurely ? Regex flavor is php (link to relevant [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gUTX7v/2)).

---

FYI: I know there are simpler ways to match this snippet, this pattern makes sense in the un-simplifed version. I solved my actual problem (with something like `(?:[^#]|(?!# header 2)#)*+`) now I am curious to understand why these two regex a and b behave differently.

Comment: There are 2 reasons, and they are all well known: 1) the `*` matches **0** or more occurrences, so `[^#]*` match match empty strings before non-matching chars, 2) since the first branch in the alternation group always matches, the second is *never* even tried.

Comment: It's because `*` can satisfy engine even if next immediate character is a `#` as long as `*` means more or ***zero***.

Comment: Ah, basic mistake... Sorry for the duplicate, thanks !